# How do I prevent Skype for Business from blinking the taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, skype-for-business

I have set `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\ForegroundFlashCount` to `1` and `ForegroundLockTimeout` to `0`.

Yet, Skype for Business still flashes the taskbar button many times whenever a message is received.

Comment: It's super frustrating......... do you know how to kill the taskbar completely ?